# After insert, update timestamp trigger with two column primary key

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a simple details table like so:

```
listid
custid
status
last_changed
```

The primary key consists of both `listid` and `custid`.

Now I'm trying to setup a trigger that sets the `last_changed` column to the current datetime every time an insert or update happens. I've found lots of info on how to do that with a single PK column, but with multiple PKs it gets confusing on how to correctly specify the PKs from the INSERTED table.

The trigger has to work in SQL Server 2005/2008/R2.

Thanks for a working trigger code!

Bonus would be to also check if the data was actually altered and only update last_changed in that case but for the sake of actually understanding how to correctly code the main question I'd like to see this as a separate code block if at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmm.... just because the primary key is made up of two columns shouldn't really make a big difference....

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgAfterUpdate ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
  UPDATE dbo.YourTable
  SET last_changed = GETDATE()
  FROM Inserted i
  WHERE dbo.YourTable.listid = i.listid AND dbo.YourTable.custid = i.custid
```

You just need to establish the JOIN between the two tables (your own data table and the `Inserted` pseudo table) on both columns...

Are am I missing something?? .....

Comment: will this work for multiple rows? all the trigger examples show code like "WHERE [id] in (SELECT [id] FROM INSERTED)", and using IN would not work correctly for two PKs.

Comment: @Tom: **YES of course!** This simply joins your table to the `Inserted` table on the two PK columns - no restriction on how many rows are affected by the operation causing the trigger to fire

Comment: works perfectly, thanks! syntax is so much clearer than in most examples.

Comment: Excuse the noob question - is Inserted an existing (and/or system) table? Also, if I was working with a slightly more complex query that updated two tables in a single query using a JOIN, will this work? I have `createTS` and `updateTS` DATETIME columns in several tables, so I suppose two triggers are needed for each table since one trigger will be responsible for updating the `createTS` column and another, for updating the `updateTS` column.

Comment: @WebUser: `Inserted` is a "pseudo table" that exists only in the context of your trigger; it has the identical structure as the table that your trigger has been defined on. And you can **definitely** update more than one column in a single trigger - absolutely **no need** for two separate triggers here!

Comment: @marc_s, that cleared up the doubt about the `Inserted` table, thanks! As far as two versus one trigger is concerned, the `createTS` is updated only once - when the record is inserted. The `updateTS` is updated every time the record is updated, including the first time, i.e. at insertion. Can this be done with a single trigger? If so, can you show that to me in an example? Thanks again.

Comment: @WebUser: if `createdTS` needs to be set on initial `INSERT` only - just define a `DEFAULT` constraint for it! No need for a trigger....

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgAfterUpdate ON dbo.YourTable
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS
      UPDATE dbo.YourTable
      SET last_changed = GETDATE()
      FROM Inserted i
      JOIN dbo.YourTable.listid = i.listid AND dbo.YourTable.custid = i.custid
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM Deleted  D Where D.listid=I.listid AND D.custid=i.custid AND (D.status=i.status)
```

Here i assuming that stasus column is not nullable. If yes, you should add additional code to check if one of columns is NULL

Comment: Do you remember why you added the "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT..." part? I know 6 years has passed, but I hope that you'll take the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check every field in trigger by comparing data from inserted and deleted table like below :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_test] ON [dbo].[table]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @old_listid INT
    DECLARE @old_custid INT
    DECLARE @old_status INT

    DECLARE @new_listid INT
    DECLARE @new_custid INT
    DECLARE @new_status INT

    SELECT @old_listid=[listid], @old_custid=[custid], @old_status = [status] FROM [deleted]

    SELECT @new_listid=[listid], @new_custid=[custid], @new_status = [status] FROM [inserted]

    IF @oldstatus <> @new_status
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TABLE table SET last_changed = GETDATE() WHERE [listid] = @new_listid AND [custid] = @new_custid 
    END

END
```

Comment: This will **NOT WORK** since `Inserted` and `Deleted` might contain **multiple rows** (when a batch statement has been executed) and your `SELECT` will fail (or pick one entry at random.....). SQL Server triggers are **NOT** executed per row - they are executed **per batch** (which might affect multiple rows)

Comment: @marc_s: I think for batch update, your answer is correct. Thanks for guidance.