# Trigger to update sum of columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know this is not a way to do it but it's a interview question

to update total = marks1 + marks2 + marks3 using a trigger.

I wrote something like this but it's not updating after an insert statement.

```
CREATE table marks
(
marks1 int,
marks2 int,
marks3 int,
total int
)

SELECT * from marks m

insert into marks values(10,10,20,0)

drop TRIGGER total_marks
create TRIGGER total_marks ON marks
AFTER INSERT
AS
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @marks1 as int
select @marks1 = inserted.marks1 FROM inserted
DECLARE @marks2 as int
select @marks1 = inserted.marks2 FROM inserted
DECLARE @marks3 as int
select @marks1 = inserted.marks3 FROM inserted
DECLARE @result as int
set @result = @marks1 + @marks2 + @marks3

update marks
set total = @result

SET NOCOUNT OFF
end
```

Comment: `after insert, update` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528899/after-insert-update-timestamp-trigger-with-two-column-primary-key

Comment: Your trigger doesn't handle multiple row inserts, updates *all* rows to the same value (rather than just the row(s) inserted), and is far more complex than necessary anyway. Where is your key?

Comment: Aside from the other issues, selecting into `@marks1` for all three marks probably wasn't helping. At least you declared variables for the other two marks even if they were never initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger doesn't handle multiple row inserts, updates *all* rows to the same value (rather than just the row(s) inserted), and is far more complex than necessary anyway. Where is your key?

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.total_marks 
 ON dbo.marks
 FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE m
    SET total = i.marks1 + i.marks2 + i.marks3
    FROM dbo.marks AS m
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON m.key = i.key;
END
GO
```

If your table really doesn't have a key (it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me), then you can say this, but it may update rows that were already updated:

```
ON m.marks1 = i.marks1 AND m.marks2 = i.marks2 AND m.marks3 = i.marks3
WHERE m.total = 0;
```