# Creating a SQL trigger to put an update time in the same row after updatу of one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `ORDER_TEST` that has columns `№`, `STATUS` and `DATE_STATUS`.

`№` is unique for each row (primary key).

I want to create a trigger that will set (update) `STATUS_TIME` after `STATUS` was updated.

I tried to use

```
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER_UPDATE_STATUS
ON ORDER_TEST
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE ORDER_TEST
    SET DATE_STATUS = {fn now()}
    FROM ORDER_TEST
    JOIN INSERTED ON ORDER_TEST.[№] = inserted.[№]
    WHERE (SELECT STATUS FROM INSERTED) <> (SELECT STATUS FROM DELETED)
```

But SQL Server says that changes will affect several rows.

Help please. What is wrong?

Comment: `№` is, with respect, a terrible name for an object. I really suggest sticking to characters within your language's base alphabet, numbers and underscores. Avoid names that must be delimit identified and especially non-standard characters.

Comment: As for the above, this is going to error when ever more than 1 row is affected, as your 2 subqueries (`SELECT STATUS FROM INSERTED` and `SELECT STATUS FROM DELETED`) will return multiple rows and error; a subquery cannot return multiple values when referenced like a scalar value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After insert, update timestamp trigger with two column primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528899/after-insert-update-timestamp-trigger-with-two-column-primary-key)

Comment: `SET DATE_STATUS = {fn now()}` Why use this obscure function syntax? And your query has all the information needed to avoid undesired updates. You simply add the condition to the where clause - `WHERE ORDER_TEST.STATUS <> deleted.STATUS;` You will need to adjust your joins and for NULL if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a datetime column in SQL Server that automatically updates when the record is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493178/need-a-datetime-column-in-sql-server-that-automatically-updates-when-the-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to add the `Deleted` table also to the Join and check if the value has changed or not.

Something like this

```
USE [TEST_DATABASE];
GO
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER_UPDATE_STATUS
ON ORDER_TEST
AFTER UPDATE
AS

UPDATE YourTable
    SET
        UpdateTimeStamp = GETDATE()
    FROM Inserted
        INNER JOIN Deleted 
            ON Inserted.KeyColumn = Deleted.KeyColumn
        INNER JOIN YourTable 
            ON YourTable.KeyColumn = Inserted.KeyColumn
        WHERE Inserted.Status <> Deleted.Status
```

Comment: `Inserted.Status <> Deleted.Status` is probably better off in the `ON` clause, rather than the `WHERE`, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank You! Works just as i need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the recursion level for triggers currently set on the DB.

If you do this:

```
SP_CONFIGURE 'nested_triggers',0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Or this:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
```

That trigger above won't be called again, and you would be safe (unless you get into some kind of deadlock; that could be possible but maybe I'm wrong).

Still, I do not think this is a good idea. A better option would be using an [INSTEAD OF trigger.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288.aspx) That way you would avoid executing the first (manual) update over the DB. Only the one defined inside the trigger would be executed.

An `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger would be like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER setDescToUpper ON part_numbers
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO part_numbers (colA, colB, part_description) 
    SELECT
        colA, colB,
        UPPER (part_description)
    FROM
        INSERTED
END
```

It depends on the recursion level for triggers currently set on the DB.

If you do this:

```
SP_CONFIGURE 'nested_triggers',0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Or this:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
```

That trigger above won't be called again, and you would be safe (unless you get into some kind of deadlock; that could be possible but maybe I'm wrong).

Still, I do not think this is a good idea. A better option would be using an INSTEAD OF trigger. That way you would avoid executing the first (manual) update over the DB. Only the one defined inside the trigger would be executed.

An `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger would be like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER setDescToUpper ON part_numbers
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO part_numbers (colA, colB, part_description) SELECT
        colA, colB,
        UPPER(part_description)
    FROM
        INSERTED
END
```

This would automagically "replace" the original INSERT statement by this one, with an explicit UPPER call applied to the `part_description` field.

An `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger would be similar (and I don't advise you to create a single trigger, keep them separated).

Also, this addresses @Martin comment: it works for multirow inserts/updates (your example does not).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this way