# Retrieve only changed rows

Tags: sql, sftp

I have a order table that has a column that tracks item order status. The results from this table is converted into csv and sent to an SFTP server, daily

The first time the file is sent, it retrieves and sends all the values from the table, but the subsequent file transfer should only contain the rows whose order status have changed

Below is an illustration:

[image]

... assume that the above table shows the results of the file the first time the file is transferred; but during the subsequent transfer, we find that the status for items 'a' and 'b' have change to 'completed' as below:

[image]

... so then the file transfer that should be sent to sftp server should only contain the two rows whose status have changed i.e

[image]

Anyone has a suggestion on how I can implement this in SQL?

Comment: Do you have any column which store an "updated_at" date for each order ? I worked on a similar use case before and we added a "updated_at" column. We also saved the "last_execution_script" datetime in a config table in the database. Then we just had to filter on orders with an "updated_at > last_execution_script"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an `updated_at` column in orders table. Then create a trigger on orders table which would update this column on an item, whenever there is a status change.
For creating a trigger refer to this answer: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69796403/8587510)